# Why is my context API not exporting? (First_name) is not exporting

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-context

Consider:

```javascript
function App() {
  const First_name = `createContext`({});
  return (
    <>
      <First_name.Provider value="`Rishikesh`">
        <Compa />
      </First_name.Provider>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
export {First_name};
```

Answer (score 0):

You *create* context inside the app and from that, you can't export it, because it is inside the curly braces. And *const* and *let* are block scope. They can't be accessed outside of the block scope ({}).

Also don't use a class name like *First_name*. That's not a good practice. Still, you can access the value of that context, but that's not fair at all. Use a class name in [upper camel case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case) (Pascal case), like *FirstName*.

```
const FirstName = createContext({});

export default function App() {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

  return (
      <>
        <FirstName.Provider value="Rishikesh"></FirstName.Provider>
      </>
    )
}

export default App;
export { FirstName };
```